# Newenvironment wrapper around widetable

Tags: tables, errors, environments

I'm trying to create a custom environment `figs` based on [`widetable`](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/archive/Archive%20directory/macros/latex2e/contrib/widetable/widetable.pdf), using `\newenvironment`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{widetable}

\newenvironment{figs}[1]{\begin{widetable}{\textwidth}{#1}}{\end{widetable}}

\begin{document}
\begin{widetable}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|}
(a) & (b) & (c) & (d) \\
\end{widetable}
\begin{figs}{|c|c|c|c|}
(a) & (b) & (c) & (d) \\
\end{figs}
\end{document}
```

I intended the `\begin{figs}...\end{figs}` part in the code to expand to the `\begin{widetable}...\end{widetable}` part right above it.

But this crashes with the error "File ended while scanning use of `\wt@finishTable`." If I remove the `\begin{figs}...\end{figs}` part from the code then it compiles perfectly well. Did I make a mistake inside the `\newenvironment`?

Comment: Basically you can't define an environment in terms of `widetable`.

Comment: Is there a reason for it, like some bad definitions in the `widetable` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{widetable}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{figs}[1]{%
\begin{widetable}{\textwidth}{#1}
  \BODY
\end{widetable}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{widetable}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|}
(a) & (b) & (c) & (d) \\
\end{widetable}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{figs}{|c|c|c|c|}
(a) & (b) & (c) & (d) \\
\end{figs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You basically can't define an environment in terms of `widetable`. Here's a workaround, but keep in mind that `widetable` is not guaranteed to work if there is a `\multicolumn` inside it spanning more than one column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{widetable}

\makeatletter
\def\figs#1{%
  \def\@tempC{figs}\setlength{\wt@width}{\textwidth}%
  \def\wt@finetabella{\end{figs}}%
  \def\wt@preamble{#1}\wt@getTable}
\let\endfigs\endwidetable
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{widetable}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|}
(a) & (b) & (c) & (d) \\
\end{widetable}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{figs}{|c|c|c|c|}
(a) & (b) & (c) & (d) \\
\end{figs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get the warning "if there is an `ifetex' package then it is not installed... the package is being emulated." I read online that this warning can be ignored, but is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: @HerngYi You can remove the warning with the `silence` package.